# Method to download json object as json file python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-2.x

I'm trying to extract the data from this [json bitcoin api](http://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/EUR.json)

stored in a json file. First I tried

```
import urllib, json
url = "http://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
print data
```

it worked at first but if I run it again, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "btc_api.py", line 4, in <module>
    data = json.loads(response.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I have to run the code periodically to get the newest currency and store it in a database. Can someone help me with this issue or any ideas how to do it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`requests`**](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) with **`json`** method it provides:

```
import requests

url = "http://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json"
data = requests.get(url).json()
```

Though if you still want to use **`urllib`** use [**`json.load`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load):

```
import urllib
import json

url = "http://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.load(response)
```

Comment: @Array you need to use load, not loads

Comment: Ok, i fixed that. Now I  get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'. :/ and the other two methods throws errors to.

Comment: If I try the other methods, it gives me  : raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded"

Comment: What str object and read? Can you use the exact code i gave you, it works without any problems

Comment: First I corrected loads in my original code with load. This gave me the str error. If I copy, paste your code into my .py file and run it, it throws No JSON object could be decoded. May it has something to do with my libs?

Comment: Urllib is builtin, requests you need to install. If you corrected your loads, it shouldn't use read(). You load from the response directly, like i showed in the example. I ran both examples several times and it returns proper json